# Reverse Order of Data table to display using play framework or Normal html

Tags: html, playframework

```
how to display data table items in the reverse order in order of id ...

back language i'am using scala 

reverse order  data in the data table or models,and display on  in view the page using,
play framework or Normal html
```

in the View page...

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.listAllpost) {
<fieldset>
@for(post<- posts){
<h3>
@post.name </h3><br/><br/>
</fieldset>
}
```

and in the application page listing the posts

```
val pos:Post=null
val postNotifiaction:PostNotification=null
def listAllpost()= Action{

    val post:List[Post]=Post.listAllPostById
    Ok(views.html.allPosts.render(Application.postNotificationForm,post,pos,postNotifiaction))
      }

def listPsts = Action { implicit request =>
        val today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
        val alert: Alert = new Alert("", "")
        Common.setAlert(alert)
        createPostForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        errors => BadRequest(views.html.createPost(errors, "There is some error","")),
    post => {
        Post.findByPostName(post.name).isEmpty match {
    case true =>  case false =>
        }
        Results.Redirect("/post")
       })
    }
```

in here i add apost in db when reload the page it is in the last..

So i want last post was in the top.. there is any way .. any one know the way ..please mention here....

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Could you rephrase your question please? If you just want to know how to reverse a [`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Seq): use its [`reverse()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Seq) method.

Comment: @Carsten i want  data in the models to display in view page in reverse order...

Comment: So please edit your question and at the very least write where your data is and how you're accessing it.

Comment: @Carsten i just update the  question...

Comment: Great, now your question contains all the code except the bit where you fetch the data from your database. If you want to reverse the order while fetching the data, do it in your `Post.listAllPostById` method. If you want to do it in the template, `@for(post <- posts.reverseIterator())` _should_ work (not tested, though).

Comment: @Carsten wait.. i just..run the programmm i think it will work

Comment: @ Carsten yeah..that's working   u can post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`List.reverseIterator()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) returns "an iterator yielding elements in reversed order", you can list your posts in reverse order by using

```
@for(post <- posts.reverseIterator()) {
    @post.name<br>
}
```